# Write a simple query and solve: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I've this error and I would like understand:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable |
> ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration |
> PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got
> 'SELECT'

It's because I have do this:

```
public function findByBookings($start, $leave): array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('SELECT * FROM room as r JOIN booking as b ON r.id = b.r WHERE b.r NOT IN 
    (SELECT b.room FROM b WHERE b.startDate <= :startDate AND b.leaveDate >= :leaveDate, OR WHERE b.startDate >= :startDate AND b.leaveDate <= :leaveDate, OR WHERE b.startDate >= :startDate AND b.leaveDate >= :leaveDate, OR WHERE b.startDate <= :startDate AND b.leaveDate <= :leaveDate)')
        ->setParameter(':start', $start)
        ->setParameter(':leave', $leave);

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;

  }
```

If I change $this->createQueryBuilder for $this->createQuery() I've another error:

> Undefined method "createQuery". The method name must start with either
> findBy, findOneBy or countBy!

Why Symfony return me this error where as the name of my function begin by "findBy"?

Thank you

Comment: `OR WHERE`...??

Comment: You think is not good?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a tree of a bare minimum setup to reproduce an environment to test my modifications to your **dql** query.

```
.
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── init.sql
└── src
    ├── Entity
    └── index.php
```

**composer.json**

```json
{
  "name": "oluwafemi.sule/experiment",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "^6.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.14",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Experiment\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Oluwafemi Sule"
    }
  ]
}
```

A room could have one or more bookings.

**src/Entity/Booking.php**

```
<?php
namespace Experiment\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="bookings")
 */
class Booking
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private string $startDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private string $leaveDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Room")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="room", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private Room|null $room = null;
}
```

**src/Entity/Room.php**

```php
<?php
namespace Experiment\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="rooms")
 */
class Room
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

**src/index.php**

```php
<?php
require __DIR__.'/..'.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

$params = [
    'password' => 'pass',
    'host' => '0.0.0.0',
    'dbname' => 'test',
    'user' => 'postgres',
    'driver' => 'pdo_pgsql',
];
$config = new Configuration();
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
$config->setProxyNamespace('Experiment');
$config->setProxyDir(sys_get_temp_dir());
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl(new AnnotationDriver(new AnnotationReader()));

$dql = <<<EOL
SELECT c.id FROM Experiment\Entity\Booking AS c JOIN c.room AS s
WHERE s.id NOT IN (SELECT r.id
     FROM Experiment\Entity\Booking AS b JOIN b.room AS r
     WHERE 
       b.startDate <= :startDate AND b.leaveDate >= :leaveDate OR  
       b.startDate >= :startDate AND b.leaveDate <= :leaveDate OR 
       b.startDate >= :startDate AND b.leaveDate >= :leaveDate OR
       b.startDate <= :startDate AND b.leaveDate <= :leaveDate)
EOL;

$connection =  DriverManager::getConnection($params);
$em = EntityManager::create($connection, $config);

$queryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();


$start = '2020-05-02';
$leave = '2020-05-02';

$query = $em
     ->createQuery($dql)
     ->setParameter('startDate', $start)
     ->setParameter('leaveDate', $leave);

$results = $query->getResult();

var_dump($results);
```

**init.sql**

```sql
create table rooms (id SERIAL);

create table bookings (
    id SERIAL,
    startDate timestamp,
    leaveDate timestamp,
    room integer
);

INSERT INTO
    rooms
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3);

INSERT INTO
    bookings
VALUES
    (1, '2023-05-01T01:00', '2023-05-01T03:00', 1),
    (2, '2023-05-01T05:00', '2023-05-01T09:00', 2),
    (3, '2023-05-03', '2023-05-04', 3);
```

- Run `composer install`
- Run the Postgres service in Docker

```bash
docker run -it --rm --name postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass -e POSTGRES_DB=test -v $(PWD)/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql postgres
```

Then run
`php src/index.php`

Comment: Thank you for answer, I've tried but I have the same thing.

Comment: The entity manager should have the createQuery method. What do you mean same thing?

Comment: ok thank's so I've add the entitymanager for the create query. I have the same error as with the code I provided. thank's for your answer

Comment: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 8: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got '*'

Comment: I think you can't just write `SELECT *`, but you should rather write `SELECT r.*`